# Retrieve last level directory name from path

Tags: java, parsing, path

I have a string that represents a path ... something like this:

```
/A/B/C/D/E/{id}/{file_name}.ext
```

The path structure could be different but in general I would like to retrieve last directory name (in the example {id}) before the file-name.

I would like to use Path java class.

Is there a simple and safe way to retrieve last directory name using Path class?

Comment: If we want to use regex, then this regex could do the trick: [`^.*?(?<lastDir>[^\/]+)\/[^\/]*?$`](https://regex101.com/r/ovEjgG/1), [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/6vNT3z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Path#getParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent--) returns a path’s parent. You can then use [`Path#getFileName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--):

```
path.getParent().getFileName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getName()` with `File` which is available

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29

```
File f = new File("C:\\Dummy\\Folder\\MyFile.PDF");
System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Which returns you `MyFile.PDF`.

(or)

```
// Path object
Path path
    = Paths.get("D:\\eclipse\\configuration"
                + "\\myconfiguration.conf");

// call getName(int i) to get
// the element at index i
Path indexpath = path.getName(path.getNameCount()-2);

// prints the name
System.out.println("Name of the file : " + indexpath);
```

Which prints `myconfiguration.conf`. Hope it helps !

Comment: He could also convert the path to File object as `new File(path.toString())`